# How to perform action on simple UIView Animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimageview

I've never done any coding before until a few weeks ago, and whilst I've made reasonable progress on my own, I'm struggling with something that I hope someone wouldn't mind helping with.

I'm trying to make a simple app for my daughter in Swift (xCode Version 7.3 - 7D175). It's a series of animations where characters pop up and down inside a moon crater.

What I want to be able to do, is call a function when one of the animated UIImages is pressed. Ideally I'd like it to play a sound when the animation is pressed (I know how to call sounds, just not in this way)

I've created a Class where I wrote the code for the animations

```
  func alienAnimate() {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0, options: [.CurveLinear, .AllowUserInteraction], animations: {
        self.center.y -= 135
             }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 3, options: [.CurveLinear, .AllowUserInteraction], animations: {
        self.center.y += 135
            }, completion: nil)

    }
```

If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciated. I guess there's probably better ways of animating, but this is all I know at the moment.

EDIT - 2nd May

OK so I eventually got it working...well, nearly :) It still doesn't work exactly as I'd like, but I'm working on it.

The animations essentially move vertically along a path (so the aliens pop up like they're coming out of a hole). The below code works, but still allows you to click on the image at the start of it's path when it's effectively down a hole.

I still need to work out how to click where it actually is now, and not be able to press its starting point.

[View of App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpBvp.png)

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    let touchLocation = touch!.locationInView(self.view)
    if self.imgAlien.layer.presentationLayer()!.hitTest(touchLocation) != nil {
        sfxPop.play()

    } else if self.imgAlien.layer.presentationLayer()!.hitTest(touchLocation) != nil {
        sfxPop.play()
    } else if self.imgAlien2.layer.presentationLayer()!.hitTest(touchLocation) != nil {
        sfxPop.play()
    } else if self.imgAlien3.layer.presentationLayer()!.hitTest(touchLocation) != nil {
        sfxPop.play()
    } else if self.imgAlien4.layer.presentationLayer()!.hitTest(touchLocation) != nil {
        sfxPop.play()
    } else if self.imgAlien5.layer.presentationLayer()!.hitTest(touchLocation) != nil {
        sfxPop.play()
    } else if self.imgUFO.layer.presentationLayer()!.hitTest(touchLocation) != nil {
        sfxPop.play()

}
```

}

Comment: Apologies if this is not enough information, happy to post more if required, I just didn't want to put too much information if it's not needed :)

Comment: i dont see any code related to images here.. just the movement of the subclass. if it is indeed the alien class, let us know so that we can answer it

Comment: It sounds like what you want to do comes out of the box with Sprite kit.  You might want to check out a Sprite kit tutorial and see if it's worth changing your implementation a bit

Comment: Hi guys, apologies for not making it clearer. In the ViewController.swift file, I created IBOutlets of type 'AlienAnimations' which is what I've called the Class with the animations in. Then I specified the image as a custom class (AlienAnimations) for the image in the storyboard. I can edit my original post and show the code for it all if needed. Sorry, first time posting here and I'm a super novice when it comes to coding !

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your have your planet and animation working up and down as you wish, what do you do is to detecting touch:

This is just an example:

```
var image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"alien.png")!
var image2 : UIImage = UIImage(named:"alienBoss.png")!
var alien1 = UIImageView(image: image)
var alien2 = UIImageView(image: image)
var alienBoss = UIImageView(image: image2)

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    if(touch.view == alien1){
        // User touch alien1, do whatever you want
    } else
    if(touch.view == alien2){
        // User touch alien2, do whatever you want
    } else
    if(touch.view == alienBoss){
        // User touch alienBoss, do whatever you want
    }
}
```

Then, you want to enable sound so you can use AVAudioPlayer library:

```
    import UIKit
    import AVFoundation

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        var player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let audioPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("alienSound", ofType: "mp3")
        var error:NSError? = nil
}
```

You can use the code below to play a sound, stop, set the volume:

```
do {
    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!))
   // to play the mp3
   player.play()
   // to stop it
   player.stop()
   // to pause it
   player.pause()
   // to set the volume
   player.volume = 0.5  // from 0.0 to 1.0
   ...
}
catch {
    print("Something bad happened.")
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I really appreciate you taking the time to do that for me. As soon as I'm done eating, I'll go give all that a try and report back :) 

Very kind of you to help.

Comment: No problem.Welcome to StackOverflow. Best thanks from who make a question is to give a vote or accept the answer as the correct answer to this question

Comment: Ok I made some tests, I've probably done something wrong as I'm getting an error. override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {  <br/>
            let touch = touches.first as! UITouch <br/>
            if(touch.view == imgAlien) { <br/>
                sfxPop.play() <br/>
                    } <br/>
                } <br/> <br/>  I get the error message : Method does not override any method from it's superclass <br/> I also get the message : Value of type 'NSSet' has no member first <br/>

Comment: I've tried looking at the documentation, but I can't see what is wrong if we have made a statement after the function override declaration. Sorry if I'm being stupid, my brain isn't always working logically with code yet, it's all so new :S

Comment: Remove override word

Comment: Ok so I got it working. The problem now is that the touch area doesn't follow the animation (only where the image began before it was animated). So the function is only called if I tap where the image originally was and not where it currently is. 

Maybe what I'm trying to do isn't possible?  Oh well, thanks for your help anyway Alessandro, don't worry about helping further, you've given me enough time already :)